# How to retrieve the drive id and Item id using SharePoint CSOM ?

Tags: rest, csom, onedrive

I'm trying to download a large file in chunks using range header. Lately, I figured that

> {sharepoint url}/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('{file relative
>   path}')/$value

does not support chunking.

As the one drive API supports chunking, I'm able to use

> {share point url}/_api/v2.0/drives/{drive id}/items/{item id}/content

But, I'm not able to retrieve the drive id and item id using CSOM so that I can pass them to this REST API. These drive id's and item id's are not the guid which is available and they look something like this

> drive id :
>   b!yEbPesQM2kwnhqNmBNjE_1-wTmg387dPlEh45G43I3QSpwqY9AihS4Llo6ayiX4f
>   item id : 01NZ3H4R8KDMNJKMULJZQKTRSAIHZEEQM8

Any leads will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The first is SharePoint REST API, the second is OneDrive. I am actually not sure if there is a bridge across these two systems.

I haven't seen any drive id or item id in that format in the SharePoint REST returns, I'd suspect they purposefully branched into the v2.0 path to keep these two systems from mixing.

Please don't get demoralized by my post, as I am not 100% sure if there is a bridge between or not, based on personal experience it looks grim, but I'm happy to learn something new if someone with more OneDrive experience posts an answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

This uses the Graph API not CSOM, but it got me unblocked:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/blahblahblah.sharepoint.com/drive`.

That's for the default site but you can put the path to another site in there too.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45406451/how-can-i-get-the-siteid-of-the-current-site-with-microsoft-graph-api
- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_get?view=odsp-graph-online#get-the-document-library-associated-with-a-group